# Have I used "on behalf of" correctly and naturally?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, idiomatic-language

> My boss gave me a bouquet of flowers **on behalf of** the whole company.

Is the use of "on behalf of" correct and natural here to mean that my boss gave me flowers which were from him and the rest of the company?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This usage is perfect and means exactly what you said.